# CSS style mysteriously overriden by unlisted style sheet / script

Tags: css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

When using twitter bootstrap with node.js and jade to style a website I am working on the `border-bottom-width` attribute is overriden by some thing when finally rendered to the screen.

If I look in the computed tab of inspect element

[image: Inspect element]

Thus no style is listed as overriding the value from 1px yet something clearly is as 0px is shown as the resolved value.

Comment: Looks like Jade isn't pre-rendering your CSS correctly.

Comment: what code does it show to you when you click on that blue link: "bootstrap.min.css" line 7?

Comment: It lists a 1px bottom border. If I try to manually override with chrome to set the boundary to any non zero value. The style gets added but the border remains resolved to 0